# Блок комментариев, который сформирован командой артисан лучше удалить?

Tags: laravel, phpdoc

Блок комментариев перед методом контроллера, его можно удалить (загромождает код) или  лучше оставить для других разработчиков?

```
/**
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $this->client->changeInStorage($input, $id);
    return redirect('/products');
}
```

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc

Comment: комментарии ни на что не влияют, там просто дано описание какие параметры и каких типов принимает метод и что он возвращает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это аннотации. Т.к. php, в основном, - язык с динамической типизацией, то типы описываются в аннотациях. Если Вы, например, используете phpstorm, то он на основании аннотаций, будет подсвечивать ворнингами методы, где возвращаемый, или передаваемый тип, не соответствует.

Answer (score 1):

На основании этих комментариев (подчинённых определенному синтаксису) - может строиться документация по методам. Очень полезно, если Вы пишете API: можно настроить автоматическое развёртывание и обновление документации на сервере.